Changing an axiom of vector space
Let $V$ be a vector space and let A be the axiom $$\exists~\textbf{0}\in V.~\forall\textbf{v}\in V.~\textbf{v}+\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}+\textbf{v}=\textbf{v}.$$ We attempt to show that A is equivalent to the following axiom A* $$\exists~!~\textbf{0}\in V.~\forall\textbf{v}\in V.~\textbf{v}+\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}+\textbf{v}=\textbf{v}.$$
We note that A provides the existence of a vector $\textbf{0}$ so in order to prove its uniqueness, we use A to show that there are no distinct alternatives of $\textbf{0}$:
Let $\textbf{0}_1$ and $\textbf{0}_2$ be addition identities of $V$. Then,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\textbf{0}_1 & = & \textbf{0}_1+\textbf{0}~\text{(by A)} \\
& = & \textbf{0}_1+\textbf{0}_2+\textbf{0}~\text{(by assumption)} \\
& = & \textbf{0}_2+\textbf{0}~\text{(by assumption)} \\
& = & \textbf{0}_2~\text{(by A)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence we have $\text{A}\implies\text{A}*$. But it is clear that the converse is true. So we have $$\text{A}\iff\text{A}*$$
which is our intended change in axioms for vector spaces.
P.S. I hope to get some criticism or feedback as to why this is possibly wrong. Just stumbled upon this but couldn't figure out a way to clearly invalidate it. Thank you for your help.

$\textbf{0}_1 = \textbf{0}_1 + \textbf{0}_2 = \textbf{0}_2$ would suffice, $\textbf{0}$ is not needed. Otherwise it's fine.

It's almost there. The only problem I see is that you assume two additive identities $0_1$ and $0_2$, but then somehow a third one, denoted by $0$, appears without having been defined. $0_1$ and $0_2$ take the role of $0$ in the statement of the axiom, and so there is not some additional $0$ there without assuming so. What you instead could do is observe that
$$0_1=0_1+0_2=0_2$$
by applying A twice: first with $0_2$ taking the role of $0$ and secondly with $0_1$ taking the role of $0$.

Thank you. Does that mean that A and A* are equivalent axioms?

@KHOOS indeed it does, for the reason you stated

Thank you for your help! Have a great day.
